Method "PATCH" not allowed error in django
I have django rest framework and with generics views. Whenever I try to make a PATCH request, I get an error that method not allowed.
Below is my views.py code
class VisitorsLogBooktbViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = VisitorsLogBooktb.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VisitorsLogBooktbSerializer

class Visitor_data(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = models.VisitorsLogBooktb.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VisitorsLogBooktbSerializer

and below is my urls.py code in the app root
urlpatterns = [
    path('', VisitorsLogBooktbViewSet.as_view(),),
    path('api/All-visitors/', Visitor_data.as_view(),),
]

I have tried changing the generics views by creating views only for updates using just generics.UpdateAPIView......But it still doesn't work.

path('api/visitors/<int:pk>/', views.Visitor_data.as_view(), name='visitor-detail'), ]
on the base of id or pk you can update retrieve and destroy an object so you have to change your urls.py like this
